# maximum calstack size exceeded on vuex commit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have this error here

[image]

I could limit the error to this line here

```
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      let ctx = this.$refs.canvas.getContext('2d')
      let { chartType, dataOptions } = this.module
      this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: chartType,
        data: dataOptions,
        options: minimizeOptions,
      })
    })
  },
```

The error comes from `dataOptions`. If i set data to `{}` everything works ok, but obviously my chart has no data then.

`this.module` is an prop that is being passed to my component. The component itself gets rendered in an `v-for` loop

```
    <module
      v-for="mod in modules"
      :module="mod"
      :key="mod._id.toString()"
    />
```

I am using here Chart.js.

I cannot find the reason for this call stack exceed error.

Maybe somebody had similar problems?

I also need to mention that this error happens when i want to toggle an global component that is placed in an layout `layout`

`dataOptions`:

```
{
   datasets: [
      {
          backgroundColor: "#34495e",
          borderColor: "bdc3c7",
          data: [0],
          label: "My first dataset"
      }
   ],
   labels: ["Start"]
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should show us what `dataOptions` is, since you have narrowed it down to it causing the problem?

Comment: @Terry sure i can , but i guess it wont help alot. also i want to say that this data doesnt need to be reactive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually does not need reactivity on this prop, so i decided to freeze it up.

```
  let { chartType, dataOptions } = Object.freeze(this.module);
```

Reactivity is gone an the error aswell. This fixed my problem.

Maybe somebody has an solution for reactive data